# Random walk with limited number of steps and 'refuel' nodes

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, network-flow, network

Here is a process to which an analogy in a different setting is of interest.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph with $F \subset V$.  Let $G$ represent, for example, a road network, and $F$ are refueling stations. A random walk (random drive) on this network is limited to $k$ steps without refueling. After refueling (visiting a node in $F$), the driver can take another $k$ steps.

Apart from road networks, are there any other analogies for such a process? Maybe for example, in social networks rumor/gossip spreading, disease spreading? It seems like there should be one since "realistic" random walks should not be infinite in practice.

A lot of theoretical properties can be proved about this process and I am looking for any literature that has anything remotely connected.

Comment: Biological processes should be somewhat similar (watering holes, hunting grounds, nests or burrows where the "fuel" is sleep")(cellular processes also might find applications).

Comment: @Nij  Thanks. What do you mean by watering holes,..? .what is the graph/network in question.

Comment: Literally, a hole where water is found, animals and nomadic people move from one to the other during migration or regular life. Figuratively, it's a term for a bar or pub, and people who are drinking will move from one to another in a random process. Whether they are still drunk when they reach the next, is based on how much "fuel" they took on at the previous place.

Comment: That's quite interesting!